# How to align text in alert dialog in android

Tags: android

I have text messages with lot of content in alert dailog .In alert dialog message with words  **Hello Android**  it will come randomly .My intent is to display this two words in same line .If line doesn't occupy two words .I need to bring Hello Android in next line can anybody tell How to do

Thanks

Comment: You should post some code

Comment: @xjasz How can i find space is available or not if space is available need to show in same line

Comment: I would just put a new line in front of those 2 words but if you really don't want to do that you could add Hello get the textview linecount then add Android then get the line count again.  If they don't equal eachother then remove them and put a newline and add them again

Comment: if it's because of the dialog's size, then check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199118/custom-dialog-size-to-match-theme-holo-light-dialog/20310592#20310592